# Selecting fields from a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've this query but I cannot select all fields because of group by clause.

How can I reformulate the query so it will retrieve all information?
I've tried to GroupBy by each field but some of them are text.

```
SELECT 

    p.Pato_Id,
    p.Description,
    p.Dated
    a.Assessment_Id,
    a.Recommendation,
    Question1 = MAX(CASE WHEN r.Question_Id = 0 THEN r.Answer_Id END),
    Question2 = MAX(CASE WHEN r.Question_Id = 1 THEN r.Answer_Id END)

FROM 
    Patos p
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 
        a.Assessment_Id
        , a.Recommendation
    FROM 
        Assessments a
    WHERE 
        a.Pato_Id = p.Pato_Id
    ORDER BY 
        a.Dated DESC
    ) a
JOIN 
    Replies r
ON 
    a.Assessment_Id = r.Assessment_Id

GROUP BY
    p.Pato_Id
```

Comment: When I try to add all fields to the group by I get this error:
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting your text field as a `nvarchar(max)` then including all the fields in the `group by`, something like:

```
SELECT 
    p.Pato_Id,
    CAST(p.Description AS nvarchar(max)),
    p.Dated,
    a.Assessment_Id,
    a.Recommendation,
    Question1 = MAX(CASE WHEN r.Question_Id = 0 THEN r.Answer_Id END),
    Question2 = MAX(CASE WHEN r.Question_Id = 1 THEN r.Answer_Id END)
FROM Patos p
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 
        a.Assessment_Id
        , a.Recommendation
    FROM Assessments a
    WHERE a.Pato_Id = p.Pato_Id
    ORDER BY a.Dated DESC
    ) a
JOIN Replies r
ON a.Assessment_Id = r.Assessment_Id
GROUP BY 
    p.Pato_Id,
    CAST(p.Description AS nvarchar(max)),
    p.Dated,
    a.Assessment_Id,
    a.Recommendation
```

Which is the text column? Assuming it is p.Description you can do this:

```
SELECT sub.*, t.Description FROM
(SELECT 
    p.Pato_Id as Pato_Id,
    t.Description as Description,
    t.Dated as Dated,
    a.Assessment_Id as Assessment_Id,
    a.Recommendation as Recommendation,
    Question1 = MAX(CASE WHEN r.Question_Id = 0 THEN r.Answer_Id END),
    Question2 = MAX(CASE WHEN r.Question_Id = 1 THEN r.Answer_Id END)
FROM Patos p
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 
        a.Assessment_Id
        , a.Recommendation
    FROM Assessments a
    WHERE a.Pato_Id = p.Pato_Id
    ORDER BY a.Dated DESC
    ) a
JOIN Replies r
ON a.Assessment_Id = r.Assessment_Id
GROUP BY 
    p.Pato_Id,
    a.Assessment_Id,
    a.Recommendation) AS sub
INNER JOIN Patos t ON
    t.Pato_Id = sub.Pato_Id
```

If it is also `Recommendation` your `Group By` becomes:

```
GROUP BY 
    p.Pato_Id,
    a.Assessment_Id
```

And you also join on that table.

Comment: I cannot do that. I've to return everything as it is.
I was thinking in a way of splitting the query in two selects but I don't see how can I do that.

Comment: Other option is to join the grouped query back to the  for the other values?

Comment: Yes, that was what I was thinking. And how can I do that?

Comment: Updated with some options

Comment: When I put the INNER JOIN It shows: 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'

Comment: Sorry - doing this without thinking - make it a subquery - editing above.